# Trouble installing ssh2-python. I need help understanding terminal error code and what I need to do next

Tags: python, terminal, macos-catalina, ssh2

I am trying to install ssh2-python but I am having trouble. I have downloaded the most up to date python (python3), pip (pip3), and installed cmake. I am getting this error below when I run the install command. Any help digesting this error code and what I should do next would be greatly appreciated!

```
% pip3 install ssh2-python
Collecting ssh2-python
  Using cached ssh2-python-0.18.0.post1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ssh2-python
  Building wheel for ssh2-python (setup.py) ... error

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-wheel-yo1dmlyx
       cwd: /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/
  Complete output (27 lines):
  -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  CMake Error at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
    Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
    system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:447 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    src/CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py", line 36, in <module>
      build_ssh2()
    File "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/_setup_libssh2.py", line 21, in build_ssh2
      check_call('cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON     -DENABLE_ZLIB_COMPRESSION=ON -DENABLE_CRYPT_NONE=ON     -DENABLE_MAC_NONE=ON -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=OpenSSL' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ssh2-python
  Running setup.py clean for ssh2-python
Failed to build ssh2-python
Installing collected packages: ssh2-python
    Running setup.py install for ssh2-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-record-fvi_ge6q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/ssh2-python
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/
    Complete output (20 lines):
    CMake Error at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
      Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
      system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:447 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      src/CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py", line 36, in <module>
        build_ssh2()
      File "/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/_setup_libssh2.py", line 21, in build_ssh2
        check_call('cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake ../libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON     -DENABLE_ZLIB_COMPRESSION=ON -DENABLE_CRYPT_NONE=ON     -DENABLE_MAC_NONE=ON -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=OpenSSL' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-install-58_k7bzh/ssh2-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fv/m4glr2xj7fzd20dv5pk9bs1c0000gn/T/pip-record-fvi_ge6q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/ssh2-python Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 I had to:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

I'm assuming this is a bug within the python package: it shouldn't depend on my system library.